# Identifying relationship for a class definition

Tags: java, software-design, class-diagram

I would appreciate some help on identifying the relationship (realisation, generalisation/specialisation etc) for a class definition. It's not a school assignment but a test question I apparently got wrong.

I have read up on the different type of [relationships possible on](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JE2_7.5.5/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/creal.html)

I think it might be a generalisation/specialisation relationship from what I have read but that is just a guess since I just don't understand the pseudo code so if someone could explained what is "happening" (or give a "real" code example of the pseudo code and explain that), I'd greatly appreciate in.

**Given the following pseudo code for a class definition what relationship will A have to B?**

```
class C {
    public B Get() {
        return new B();
    }
}

class B {
    public void SomeOperation(A object) {
        object.DoSomething();
    }
}

class A {
    private C m_c;

    public void DoSomething() {
        ...
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse(B b) {
        ...
        m_c.Get().SomeOperation(this);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no generalisation/ specialisation going on here. You can see that because of the absence of the word `extends` in the class definitions.

Comment: Even though I do not know which relationship type it is, I can at least say that it is most certain not a *generalisation/ specialisation*. For that `B` had to be derived from `A` in some way. But in this case there is no inheritance to be seen anywhere. The only thing I see is that there is some sort cycle when `DoSomethingElse(B b)` is called: `A` calls `Get()` on `C`, `C` calls `SomeOperation(A object)` on `B`, `B` calls `DoSomething()` on `A`. `A -> C -> B -> A`

Comment: If this is verbatim from a test, they should know not to start a method with a capital letter lol

Comment: B references A, and A references B as well as C, and C references B

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that if there is no extends, it can't be generalisation/ specialisation, that really helped.

Does anyone know of any other tips of things to look for when trying to figure out the relationship from (pseudo) code?

Comment: I think the teacher work with C# too, probably why the method naming follows PascalCase

Answer (score 0):

The class B uses an A object in the definition of its opeartions.  This means that B has a [usage dependency](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JE2_7.5.5/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cusage.html) to A.

In the same way,  A uses a B oject in the definition of its opereations.  This means that A has a usage dependency to B.

The usage dependency means that the one class needs to know about the other because it uses some objects, for example as parameter or return of a method.  It's a very light relationship.

If we follow the path of execution of `A.DoSomethingElse(B)`, we'll notice that this will call a method from C which creates a B.  It would be tempting to see also a creation relationship.  However, there are several of reasons not to model this:

- `A.DoSomethingElse(B)` returns `C.Get()`.  We know, looking at the code, that `Get()` creates a B object. But it's not A that creates it, it's C.  In view of encapsulation, we should not take any advantage of the internals of C.  We should limit our knowledge to the the few things we know, i.e. a B object can be returned but we don't know if it's a new or an existing one.
- Moreover,  one could claim that  `A.DoSomethingElse(B)` uses/creates a B which is returned by `C.Get()`, but that `C.Get()` in the function body is implementation detail. We could easily imagine to have the same UML diagram, but with an implementation that uses a differently body? So this is a reason more not to refer to this rsecond dependency relationship.